# OpenGL GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP; seemingly not getting the Z Coordinate to affect drawing

Tags: opengl, gl-triangle-strip

I'm trying to draw a line using a GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP that will go deeper or more shallow with the z coordinate, but the the z value I'm passing into glVertex3f() doesn't seem to affect the perceived width.  In the code below (a modified example from OpenGL Programming Guide), the line should start closer to the perspective (larger), and get farther (smaller).

Would you point to my mistake, or a topic in which this it is addressed?

```
void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
}
void display(void)
{
    GLdouble gran = 5.0;
    GLdouble width = 7.0;
    GLdouble theta = 1.047197551;
    GLdouble halfPi = 3.1459/2;
    GLdouble refpx = 50.0;
    GLdouble refpy = 50.0;
    GLdouble startr = 1.0;
    GLdouble startg = 1.0;
    GLdouble startb = .5;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //glLoadIdentity();
    //glScalef(2.0, -.5,1.0);
    //glRotatef(45.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

        for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            glColor3f(startr / i, startg / (20 - (i%20)), startb);

            GLdouble x1 = refpx + width*cos(theta + halfPi);
            GLdouble x2 = refpx + width*cos(theta + halfPi*3);
            GLdouble y1 = refpy + width*sin(theta + halfPi);
            GLdouble y2 = refpy + width*sin(theta + halfPi*3);

            glVertex3f(x1,y1, (GLdouble)i/40.0);
            glVertex3f(x2,y2, (GLdouble)i/40.0);

            refpx += gran*cos(theta);
            refpy += gran*sin(theta);
            if(i % 9 == 0) {
                theta += halfPi/8;
            }
            if(i == 20) {
                theta -= halfPi/2;
            }
            if(i == 5) {
                theta -= halfPi/2;
            }
        }
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glFlush();
}
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, (GLdouble) w, 0.0, (GLdouble) h, -1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(450, 450);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to *simulate* perspective or do you want *actual* perspective?  If you want *actual* perspective you'll have to use something like `gluPerspective()` instead of `glOrtho()`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! I would like to simulate perspective, since the reason Im researching this is to add functionality to a program whose drawing routines are already set up that way.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the projection matrix to just an orthographic view. This means that changes in the distance from the camera will not affect the size of the object on the screen.

In a perspective projection far things are smaller, that is not true for an orthographic projection.

So in your vertex calculations the Z coordinate is controlled by i, but not the X and Y, they are only controlled by the trigonometry, and in particular, while `refpx` and `refpy` change, the size of the object in the XY plane never does (because the only variation is a sin or cosine term added to the `refpx` and `refpy` values).

So that's why: it can't vary, because you've got nothing in the math that calculates X and Y coordinates that varies the size by distance. On its own Z will make no difference to the size on screen unless you set a perspective transform in the projection matrix. Use `gluPerspective` for ease, or assemble your own camera matrix, the math is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection

Comment: Thanks for the answers!  I got the functionality I needed using the gluPerspective state.  It was much easier than I thought, and I made some pretty neat classes for drawing wider-than-ten-pixel lines using the GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP too.  Thanks again.

Comment: sorry it took so long sir, I really appreciate the answer, and it was exactly what I needed.  Can't upvote yet though as I don't have 15 rep yet haha!